# Datatables: How to disable filtering after init

Tags: javascript, datatable

On my page I'm running one datatables init script which can initialize multiple tables at once. Now let's say I want to change some options, e.g. disable filtering, on one of those tables but not all, what would be the best way to approach this?

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/HEDvf/1165/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dataTable').dataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
    });
    $('#example2').dataTable({
        "bFilter": false
    });
});
```

As you can see I have 2 tables in html loaded, I initialize both of them at the same time by selecting the '.datatable' class, which they both have.
Then I would like to disable filtering for the 2nd table, to select this table I use the id 'example2' which only the 2nd table has. However changing the setting for this table doesn't work, the popup indicates I can't reinitialize a table, but should I otherwise change an already initialize table's options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the existing DataTable object by calling dataTable with no arguments:

```
var dt = $('#example2').dataTable();
```

I don't know which values are capable of being modified after the fact, so it may or may not work changing it then:

```
dt.DataTable.settings.bFiltered = false;
```

If you need to do it at initialization time I can think of two options.  First, is to filter it out before calling dataTable

```
$('.dataTable').not('#example2').dataTable(...);
$('#example2').dataTable(.. other options ...);
```

Alternatively, create a mechanism for setting those options at the html level:

```
$('.dataTable').each(function(k,ele) {
    ele = $(ele);
    var opts = {
      sPaginationType: ele.data('pagination-type') || 'full_numbers',
      bFilter: ele.data('bfilter') !== 'false'
    }
    // or only set it if it exists
    if (ele.data('bfilter')) {
       opts.bFilter = ele.data('bfilter') === 'true';
    }
    ele.dataTable(opts);
 });
```

That may be a little overkill but you could make html similar to:

```
<div class="datatable" data-bfilter="false" data-pagination-type="mypagination_option"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm acutally thinking about implementing your last suggestion as it looks like the nicest option and I might need to set some additional options dependant of the table contents in the future. However the syntax is not entirely clear to me: The first option (pagination) I think means 'use data-pagination-type if passed, otherwise default to 'full numbers'', is that correct? How does the bFilter option work, there seems to be no default, correct?

Comment: Yes, the string values would be easy because you can default those.  The boolean I am assuming leaving it out would be true.  You could instead check for the attribute and then set the true/false flag if it exists (not as part of the creation of the object). Then just let the defaults kick in if its not an attribute.  I've updated the example to show that.  And corrected !== false to !== 'false' which is a string comparison.

Comment: Yes I got it now, thanks! One small issue found in your code: $('.dataTable').each(function(ele) should be $('.dataTable').each(function(k,ele). Since otherwise 'ele' would be the key of the array and doesn't work with the rest of the code. Otherwise it works just fine, many thanks! If you update your answer with the issue I mentioned I will accept it

Comment: Just found out that (in Chrome at least) the data-* attributes passed via html are actual booleans and not strangs as you mentioned in your last comment. The code only works for me if I do a '=== true' comparison without quotes around true.